# CasperJS - Loop over popup links on Page A and return to Page A after scraping all popups?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I have Page A which have 9 popup links, and I need to extract the info from each popup. After this, I need to return to Page A and continue to work on it.

I used the waitForPopup and withPopup in a for loop, and I think it is the right way to open and close each popup. but the weird thing is that I got the info from the first popup repeated 9 times. I spent the whole night to get it right, but was stuck. Please take a look at my code below. Thanks.

**Update**
I found a link state the exact problem.
[Casperjs - Is ThenClick Or Any 'then Function' Synchronized Function?](https://qnalist.com/questions/5140836/is-thenclick-or-any-then-function-synchronized-function)

> Inside my script, there is a while loop, I discover my script will jump to the end of while loop just before the thenClick

For your information:

```
1> The code is part of the var suite_1 = function() { ...my code... }

2> The regex /fulltext/ here is based on the popup links 
(only the Gid value varies), like url=http://www.***.com/fulltext_form.aspx&Gid=788...

3> I also have some debug info.

[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: xpath selector: (//a[@class="main-ljwenzi"])[9]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: xpath selector: (//a[@class="main-ljwenzi"])[9]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: xpath selector: (//a[@class="main-ljwenzi"])[9]
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.***.com/fulltext_form.aspx&Gid=788, type=LinkClicked, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
```

...And ...

```
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 119/122 http://www.***.com/fulltext_form.aspx&Gid=252923 (HTTP 200)

The program is expected to open the link with Gid=788, but after some _step, it still open the Gid=252923, which is the first popup.
```

**Code**

```
this.then(function() {

    var count = this.getElementsInfo('a.main').length;
    this.echo(count + ' fulltext links found:', 'INFO');

    for (var i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {

    //According to the output,
the program will run the this.capture 9 times,
before run the following lines of code 9 times

        this.capture('before the click - ' + i + '.png');

        this.thenClick(x('(//a[@class="main"])[' + i + ']'));

        this.waitForPopup(/fulltext/, function() {
            this.echo('Popup opened', 'INFO');
            this.echo(this.getTitle(), 'INFO');
        }, null, 10000);

        this.withPopup(/fulltext/, function() {

            this.echo(this.getTitle(), 'INFO');
            this.waitForSelector('#tbl_content_main', function() {
                // do something
            });
        });

        this.then(function() {
            this.echo('Back to the main page' + this.getTitle(), 'INFO_BAR');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple example to test your case:

HTML(popup.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <button class="popup" id="casperjs" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://casperjs.org/')">casperjs</button>
    <button class="popup" id="phantomjs" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://phantomjs.org/')">phantomjs</button>
    <button class="popup" id="nodejs" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://nodejs.org/')">nodejs</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost:63342/popup.html')

casper.then(function () {
    var count = casper.getElementsInfo('.popup').length
    var counter = 1
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        casper.then(function () {
            var selector = 'body > div > button:nth-child(' + counter + ')';
            var text = casper.getElementInfo(selector).text
            casper.click(selector)
            casper.waitForPopup(text, undefined, undefined, 20000)
            casper.withPopup(text, function () {
                casper.echo(casper.getTitle())
            })
            counter ++
        })
    }
})

casper.run()
```

Output:

```
$ casperjs popup.js 
CasperJS, a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS and SlimerJS
PhantomJS | PhantomJS
Node.js
```

It works as expected.

---

So, your code have 2 problems:

1. should wrap the whole code inside the for-loop into a then.
2. should use another counter instead of `i` to make selector(you can echo the value of `i` to see it's always `count`. In my case, that's 3).

And there is nothing to do with `thenClick`. You can replace the `click` to `thenClick` in my example code, and everything remains the same... If you take a look at the implementation of `thenClick`, you will find the reason behind my statement...

Try this:

```
this.then(function() {

    var count = this.getElementsInfo('a.main').length;
    this.echo(count + ' fulltext links found:', 'INFO');
    var counter = 1 // +
    for (var i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {
        this.then(function() { //+
            this.capture('before the click - ' + counter + '.png');//edit

            this.thenClick(x('(//a[@class="main"])[' + counter + ']'));//edit

            this.waitForPopup(/fulltext/, function() {
                this.echo('Popup opened', 'INFO');
                this.echo(this.getTitle(), 'INFO');
            }, null, 10000);

            this.withPopup(/fulltext/, function() {

                this.echo(this.getTitle(), 'INFO');
                this.waitForSelector('#tbl_content_main', function() {
                    // do something
                });
            });

            this.then(function() {
                this.echo('Back to the main page' + this.getTitle(), 'INFO_BAR');
            });
            counter ++ //+
        })//+
    }
});
```

---

If you are curious about why should use another counter, you may read my answer on another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562169/asynchronous-process-inside-a-casperjs-script-for-while-loop/37565110#37565110).

Comment: Hi Sayakiss, I tried to wrap the code in a then function, but it failed. It stoped at `[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: xpath selector: (//a[@class="main-ljwenzi"])[10]`, since there's only 9 links. It seemed that the for loop simply ran 9 times, and then ran the click part of code. My code is about 200 lines, can I just email you the code?

Comment: @user5404480 Could you please upload the whole scripts? Something like gist will be fine...

Comment: 1. You can focus on popup, and write a simple script on another website(but it can reproduce your problem). 2. If you are lazy, you can send the code to my email: `zhushuierjirou@gmail.com`.

Comment: @ Sayakiss as I stated in the Update part. The popup part is ok (verified by the screenshots and simple tests), and the problem may be caused by thenClick.

Comment: @user5404480 I think you should use another counter, not `i`, to make `x('(//a[@class="main"])[' + i + ']'`. Because `i` will always be `count` in your then step...

Comment: @ Sayakiss I don't quite get what you say. Can you specify it? Thanks.

Comment: @user5404480 There is nothing wrong with `thenClick`, and you can see my update...

Comment: @ Sayakiss I tried what you do, but unfortunately I still get the same results.

Comment: @user5404480 Have you tried my example code? It works well in my environment(`phantomjs 2.1.1` and `casperjs 1.1.0-beta5`). If my example works well, you should check your code by yourself since I have no idea about why you code fails...

Comment: @ Sayakiss I sent my code in a zip file to you again. My phantomjs is 2.1.1 and casperjs is 1.1.1. Please check it out. I will try the example today. Thanks.

Comment: @user5404480 I will play OverWatch the whole weekend... See you next week :)... Besides, I did't receive your email.... You may try to send it by Gmail...

Comment: @ Sayakiss I actually sent you the email twice using my gmail. Do you have another email? Thanks.

Comment: @user5404480 How about post it to gist then delete it after problem solved?

Comment: @user5404480 replied.

Comment: @user5404480 if there is no further questions, please accept my answer...

Comment: @ Sayakiss Sorry, you said you "replied", but I didn't see it. :(

Comment: @user5404480 Or try that [code](https://gist.github.com/Sayalic0/ea6aeaf9c790a14c797de254c85943dd)

Comment: @user5404480 There 3 flaws in your code,1. should wrap the whole code inside the for-loop into a then. 2. should use another counter instead of i to make selector 3. should waitPopup for gid (not full text)